# Tailwind - Conditional class rendering

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, storybook

I'm trying to play around with Reactjs, storybook and tailwind to create a custom UIUX library, but I cannot make work the conditional rendering of the classes, it won't work in the storybook at least (for any class, rounded, bg-color, color, etc), I cannot see any change and inspecting the CSS, no CSS is applied.

**EDIT:**

The classes I'm trying to add are not concatenated, they are full class names such as "bg-red-500", "bg-green-600", etc.

I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames';

interface ButtonProps {
   label: string;
   color: string;
   bgColor: string;
   size: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
   rounded?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'full';
   disabled?: boolean;
   onClick?: (event: MouseEvent | any) => void;
}

const Button = ({ label, bgColor, color, size, rounded }: ButtonProps) => {
   const DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = color ? color : 'bg-green-500';
   const DEFAULT_ROUNDED = rounded ? 'rounded-' + rounded : 'rounded-full';

   const btnClass = cx(DEFAULT_BG_COLOR, DEFAULT_ROUNDED);

   console.log(btnClass);

   return (
      <button className={btnClass} onClick={() => console.log('Clicked')}>
         <div> {label} </div>
      </button>
   );
};

export default Button;
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: use a switch case for `rounded` and assign classes to variable based on switch cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there are 2 issues with your code.

1st which i'm absolute certain is that you shouldn't concatenate tailwind classes because these classes can't be detected by tailwind therefore are not included in the compiled file. You can read more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names).

that said if you insist, you could [**safelist**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) the classes you want to concatenate.

and 2nd if regular classes are not working, then you should make sure all the files with tailwind classes are included in the `content` array in **tailwind config** file

Comment: Hi Evangelos, actually I'm not trying to concatenate classes, I'm trying to join them, please see my edit so you can have a more general overview of the problem. If I pass the class name it works, but that's not what I want.